# CPU Upgrade from Intel Core i3-2120 to Intel Core i5-2400

Tags: cpu, upgrade, intel-core-i5, intel-core-i3

I am currently using an older Acer Aspire AM3970 computer with an Intel Core i3-2120 and I was wondering if it would be possible to upgrade the CPU to an Intel Core i5-2400?

My hardware building experience consists of RAM upgrades and that is it. I have some friends who can help me perform the upgrade, I am just wondering if it is possible to upgrade before I purchase the CPU.

Thank you!

Comment: It could work, but you need to keep in mind that the i5 produces up to 30 W more heat. The existing cooling solution is most likely insufficient.

Comment: does not appear the two have significant TDP differences

Answer (score 0):

Other than cooling issues between the 65w tdp of the [i3-2120](http://ark.intel.com/products/53426) and the [i5-2400](http://ark.intel.com/products/52207) at 95wTDP. The issue would be if the motherboard bios supports the larger core chip. You may want to look into the [i5-2400S](http://ark.intel.com/products/52208) which has the lower operating temp of 65w TDP and matches the designed cooling for your chassis.